# Nginx docker container on host network don't serve angular app

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

My goal was to run **angular app** in container with **nginx**.
I want the container with application to be in my host network.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:10.11.0-alpine as node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.14-alpine

COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/dist/gui /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
  }
}
```

And my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  gui:
    container_name: gui
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
        context: gui
```

`$ docker-compose up` starts the container. 
But there is nothing present on **localhost:80**.

Where is the problem? Nginx do not serve application?

Comment: Did you even map the 80 port in the docker-compose.yml? What do you mean by "nothing present"?

Comment: If you use "host" mode as the network mode you dont need to map any ports

Answer (score 0):

- You dont start the nginx, put this `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` end of the Dockerfile. [Official Nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/d3d1bcf9227e28e6ccc421090462faa98d5c62b4/Dockerfile)

Comment: The container starts, but still nginx do not serve application. 
These are container logs after I try access `localhost:80`:  

```gui    | 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2018:08:55:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
```  <br/>

Moreover, browser dev tools shows following error:  <br/>

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

It appearred I wrote Dockerfile, nginx.conf and docker-compose.yml correctly. 
The problem was in angular application, which were unable to compile, so 
`RUN npm run build` was failing.

Running application locally with `npm start` didn't reveale the problem, because the live-reload mode was active. Only fully compilation couldn't be finished.

@Ntwobike
Thanks for your try. Command `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` was also unnecessary.